# Netbeans: Is it possible to create a project using CLI

Tags: netbeans, command-line-interface

Is it possible to create a project using CLI?

> $ netbeans -type html-js -name myproject

Comment: [1] From the command line **cd** to the **bin** directory containing **netbeans.exe**. [2] Submit the command **netbeans --help** [3] You will be shown details of the arguments that can be provided when NetBeans is launched. [4] You will now be now able to answer your own question.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I guess, it is not possible. I am on MacOS.                           > --open file1[:line1]...   open specified file(s), possibly at given location; can also pass project directories
  --open-group NAME         open a project group by name
  --close-group             close any open project group
  --list-groups             list available project groups

Core options:
  --laf <LaF classname> use given LookAndFeel class instead of the default
  --fontsize <size>     set the base font size of the user interface, in points
  --locale <language[:country[:variant]]>

Comment: Correct, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible. Thank you guys for confirming. I added to NetBeans forum as feature request!